# Restarting httpd kills scripts executed from PHP

Tags: php, apache-httpd

My game server has a custom PHP administration interface, which can run the server manually by running the start shell script with `exec` and `sudo -E`. However, if I restart httpd using `service httpd restart`, both the script and the actual game server get killed, too. How can I change this behaviour so that only the web server get killed, or run the game server some other way?

Answer (score 1):

When you access the web-page (PHP script), the content is sent by one instance (sub-process) of the httpd server process. When you restart the httpd server, the script is informing the server to die, which will kill all the sub-processes too, including the PHP instance running the script itself. **Basically the script is effectively committing suicide.**

Try using **"apachectl -k graceful"** which will restart the server gracefully, meaning only server process will be restarted, but current sessions will be allowed to complete. Your script should not die.

Comment: It would be more clear to say php is a module⁄child then using a vague "it is coming"

Comment: Using graceful restart will DoS your service : no new connections will be accepted and served until all the childs(gameservers) will exit

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin , when using "graceful", new gameservers will start, but old gameservers will not be killed.

Comment: @Prem as far as I remember [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html) : The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're not serving anything). The parent re-reads its configuration files and re-opens its log files. As each child dies off the parent replaces it with a child from the new generation of the configuration, which begins serving new requests immediately.

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin , my reading of that is : before graceful, there is one Parent & N subprocesses (with old configuration) and after graceful, the parent starts replacing each subprocess with new instance(with new configuration). For few moments, there will be both old processes & new processes running simultaneously. In case of "restart", all N subprocesses are killed, so there is no moment with both old processes & new processes running simultaneously. Basically, "no new connections will be accepted and served until all the gameservers exit" is **not true** for **graceful**.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro , based on your feedback , I have made a slight change in wording.

Comment: @Prem as far as I remember there's no replacement, but waiting for old workers to finish and AFTER this - restart. I've made a Perl daemon based on a standart CPAN modules and just connected to it via simple XML-RPC queries, and has no problem with load ballancing(a set of web interface Apaches + a set of dedicated servers for gameservers)

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin , last comment here (because this web-page is advising me to move to "chat" web-page) : The Manual DOES NOT say "**When all child processes die**, Parent replaces them all with new instances **all at once**" . . . . Rather, the manual DOES say "**As each child dies**, Parent replaces that child with a new child , which begins **serving new requests immediately**" where there will be some old child processes still running . . .

Answer (score 1):

I used to solve exactly this problem for my game servers by writing a perl daemon that owned and controlled gameservers, and answered ad a web service to outer world. Simply put, but effective.